# Error: VS2019 is throwing 2 errors after creating .NET CORE 2.1 Web Application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, web-applications, asp.net-core-2.1

I need some help with two errors I get in VS2019.

When I create a .Net Core 2.1 Web Application, I receive 2 errors without having changed thing. I have followed my company's standard before and have never seen this.

### Errors

> 1. Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Razor\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.DesignTime.targets"
>      was not imported by "C:\Program
>      Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\build\netstandard2.0\Sdk.Razor.CurrentVersion.targets"
>      at (868,3), due to the file being invalid.
> 2. MSB4024 The imported project file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>      Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Razor\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.DesignTime.targets"
>      could not be loaded. Root element is missing.

Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the issue I had to completely uninstall Visual studio and reinstall it.

After the reinstall it worked perfectly.